# Name hiding from inherited classes

Tags: c++

I have the following sample code and I wanted to know the correct way to get access to the Pass method in the CBar class. Currently I have found 3 ways to get access to this method and they are as follows:

1. Casting the object, ((CBar *) &foo)->Pass(1, 2, 3);
2. Using this syntax, foo.CBar::Pass(1,2,3);
3. Use the "using" syntax in the CFoo class declaration, using CBar::Pass.

The following is an example of a simple project to test this capability.

Foo.h

```
#include "bar.h"
class CFoo :
    public CBar
{
private:
    double m_a;
    double m_b;
public:
    CFoo(void);
    ~CFoo(void);

    void Pass(double a, double b);
};
```

Foo.cpp

```
#include "Foo.h"
CFoo::CFoo(void)
{
    m_a = 0.0;
    m_b = 0.0;
}
CFoo::~CFoo(void)
{
}

void CFoo::Pass(double a, double b)
{
    m_a = a;
    m_b = b;
}
```

Bar.h

```
class CBar
{
    int m_x;
    int m_y;
    int m_z;
public:
CBar(void);
~CBar(void);

void Pass(int x, int y, int z);
};
```

Bar.cpp

```
#include "Bar.h"

CBar::CBar(void)
{
    m_x = 0;
    m_y = 0;
    m_z = 0;
}

CBar::~CBar(void)
{
}

void CBar::Pass(int x, int y, int z)
{
    m_x = x;
    m_y = y;
    m_z = z;
}
```

And my main class DoStuff.cpp

```
#include "DoStuff.h"
#include "Foo.h"

CDoStuff::CDoStuff(void)
{
}

CDoStuff::~CDoStuff(void)
{
}

int main()
{
    CFoo foo, foo1, foo2;

    //This only gets to the Pass method in Foo.
    foo.Pass(2.5, 3.5);

    //Gets access to Pass method in Bar.
    foo1.CBar::Pass(5,10,15);

    //Can also case and access by location for the same result??
    ((CBar *) &foo2)->Pass(100,200,300);

    return 0;
}
```

Are each of these options viable?  Are some preferred?  Are there pitfalls with using any one of the methods listed?

I am especially curious about the foo.CBar::Pass(1,2,3) syntax.

Thanks,

B

Comment: If you want to call `CBar::Pass()`, then use `foo.CBar::Pass(1,2,3)`.  Using `((CBar *) &foo2)->Pass(100,200,300);` won't "work correctly" if `Pass()` is virtual and overridden in `CFoo` (to be clear I know that's not the case here -- but you *could* declare `CBar::Pass(double, double, double)` virtual and also have a second, overloaded `CFoo::Pass(double, double, double)`, and in that case it would override) -- if by "work" you mean "run `CBar::Pass()`".  (Of course, it "works correctly" according to the C++ language spec.)

Comment: Why not just do `((CBar)foo).Pass()`?

Comment: @texasbruce: Because it will create a separate temporary object of type `CBar` and call the method for the temporary. The OP does not want to call it for a temporary. The OP wants to call the method for  `foo` specifically. For that he can do `((CBar &) foo).Pass()`, but not what you suggest.

Comment: @AndreyT Ah that makes sense. Learning everyday!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this specific example all methods ultimately produce the same outcome.

In general case the outcomes might be different.

The "cast" method `((CBar *) &foo)->Pass(1, 2, 3);` will preserve the dynamic nature of the call if `Pass` happens to be a virtual function. The cast can be performed in terms of reference type, BTW, `((CBar &) foo).Pass(1, 2, 3);`. And using C++ style casts is a better idea in such situations.

The "qualified name" method `foo.CBar::Pass(1,2,3);` will suppress the dynamic nature of the call if `Pass` happens to be a virtual function, i.e. it is guaranteed to call `CBar::Pass`.